# How do I normalize a set of numbers for display on a graph?

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to display rainfall precipitation intensity on a graph. I have a set of 60 data points, where 0.002 corresponds to drizzle and 0.4 corresponds to heavy rain. But if I just chart that data, the drizzle barely registers on the graph.

So on a scale of 100, I would need to get drizzle (~0.002) to be around 10, light rain (~0.017) to be around 25, moderate rain (~0.1) to be around 50, and heavy rain (~0.4) to be around 80.

I've tried multiplying ranges of numbers, but if I'm multiplying 0.001-0.005 times 10, and 0.006-0.009 times 8, then there's a spike in the graph that shouldn't be there.

So what's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: It is common practice to plot the logartihm of the data to have better visibility of small values.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You can calculate the logarithm of your data: log(0.002) = -2.6989 , etc.. And then you plot the new set of datapoints. You shouldn't plot points with precipitaion 0 because log(0) is not defined.